# What is the best Shopify API plugin for calculating accurate, LTL freight rates?

Tags: api

Most APIs I've used take too long to generate a freight rate and so customer's end up abandoning carts. We've tried a custom system based on shipping averages that took about a year to develop, but even that is not specific enough. Our internal sales team, who once depended on the website to give accurate shipping quotes, is no longer referring to it.

For a company that ships commercial equipment across Canada, some of which is shaped awkwardly—is there any shipping API that you could recommend?

If this is not the sub for this sort of question, can you direct me elsewhere?